# LinearLayout being used as button stuck in pressed state

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a custom layout for a phone dialer. For each number in the dialer i'm using a LinearLayout with some TextViews inside it.

**Problem**: When an `onClickListener` is set to the custom LinearLayout and it is subsequently pressed by the user, it gets stuck in the pressed state and does not revert to the default item in the state list when released. If I don't set an `onClickListener` to the LinearLayout, the state correctly changes to pressed and then unpressed.

Debugging via Android Studio's layout inspector shows that the LinearLayout still has `isPressed() == true` after the user has released. I've also tried an ImageButton and Button instead of the LinearLayout and it exhibits similar behavior. The app's theme inherits from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge`.

The layout of the fragment containing the dialer buttons:

```
 <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="2">

        <TableRow
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

            <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#e2e2e2"/>

            <DialerButton
                    android:id="@+id/keypad2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
...
```

The LinearLayout used for the DialerButton class (which is a basic class that just overrides LinearLayout and inflates the following layout) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/dialpad_btn_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNumeral"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="2"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLettering"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="ABC"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The dialpad_btn_background.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/dark_grey"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

The code to attach the OnClickListener to the LinearLayout is standard:

```
 keypad1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               /// ... Do work ...
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use ImageButton instead of a whole LinearLayout as ImageButton will automatically have this feature or if you are concerned about the design you should use the card layout.[This is a calculator where I've used Imagebutton for the keys.](https://github.com/VishalPVijayan/Android_Calculator)

Comment: I appreciate your response, we were using ImageButton already (with the same state list resource) and it had the same issue. This custom LinearLayout was an attempt to resolve the issue but it happens to both the ImageButton and the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a way to fix this using layouts, but I was able to get around it programatically. This doesn't address the root of why the LinearLayouts or the ImageButtons were getting stuck in the pressed state though, or why the state list was not working as expected.

First, I went back to using ImageButton instead of a custom LinearLayout since that made no difference with regards to the pressed state. By attaching a touch listener and programmatically setting the background of the ImageButtons on `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, I got the results I need. Here's the snippet for how I did this:

```
 View.OnTouchListener touchListener = (v, event) -> {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_dialpad_bg, null));
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_dialpad_bg_pressed, null));
            }
            return false;
        };

keypad0.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
keypad1.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
...
```